# GHC TypeLits overhead

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there any overhead of using `Sing` from [GHC.TypeLits](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/libraries/base/GHC-TypeLits.html)? For example for the program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module Test (test) where

import GHC.TypeLits

test :: Integer
test = fromSing (sing :: Sing 5)
```

GHC generates core code:

```
Test.test1 :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [] 100 0}]
Test.test1 = __integer 5

Test.test :: GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
[GblId,
 Str=DmdType,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=0, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, WorkFree=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=ALWAYS_IF(unsat_ok=True,boring_ok=True)}]
Test.test =
  Test.test1
  `cast` (<GHC.TypeLits.NTCo:SingI> <GHC.TypeLits.Nat> <5> ; (<GHC.TypeLits.TFCo:R:SingNatn
                                                                 <5>> ; <GHC.TypeLits.NTCo:R:SingNatn
                                                                           <5>>)
          :: GHC.TypeLits.SingI GHC.TypeLits.Nat 5
               ~#
             GHC.Integer.Type.Integer)
```

Is this code equivalent of `Test.test = __integer 5` and value will be computed in compile time or not?

Comment: main overhead - devs could easily change the behavior of inner libraries without notification everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is equivalent to `Test.test = __integer 5`, the `cast` part is just type system noise (you can read about what it means in the paper ["System F with Type Equality Coercions"](http://research.microsoft.com/~simonpj/papers/ext-f/fc-tldi.pdf) by Martin Sulzmann, Manuel M. T. Chakravarty, Simon Peyton Jones and Kevin Donnelly). Relevant quote:

> Cast expressions have no *operational* effect, but they serve to
>   explain to the type system when a value of one type should be treated
>   as another.

**Edit:** Actually, with GHC 7.6 the [assembly code](https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/6718150) for `test = fromSing (sing :: Sing 5)` is different from the code for `test = 5` and apparently there actually *is* some overhead, but this issue seems to be fixed in HEAD.